# Whilst setting up Azure Active Directory, do we require physical (On Premise) Active Directory server?

Tags: azure, active-directory

We have couple of ubuntu systems and ofcourse windows systems, all of those we want to put under the AD, to access the Azure Cloud. But while trying to setting up the Azure AD, from there it gives an MSI file, whilst installing that in windows machine it gives error stating that this file can only be installed on Server OSes. Is there any other way of doing it ?

Also, how to sync/add ubuntu devices in Azure AD.

Thank you in Advance for answers.

Comment: can you please add more details with what you are trying to accomplish?  Computers do not need to be part of Azure AD in order to 'access Azure Cloud'

Comment: @CtrlDot : I am sorry for not clearly mentioning that. The goal is that we want to set up Active Directory in our organization and can that be achieved through Azure AD ?